# Best and most efficient algorithm to find out if a value exists in multiple collections

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I am trying to write the most efficient algorithm to find out which numbers exist in all lists of numbers without using third party code.

Consider this figure. Number 36 and 41 exist in all lists.

[image]

I have written a program that finds those numbers using this algorithm written in a Golang-like pseudo code:

```
func findAllEqualValues(lists []List) {
   foreach list in lists {
      label: foreach value in list.Values {

          var existsInAll = false
          foreach list2 in lists {
            if Exists(list2.Values, value) {
               existsInAll = true
             } else {
               existsInAll = false
               continue label
            }
         }

         if existsInAll {
            printf("Value %d exists in all lists", value)
         }
      }
   }
}

func Exists(values []Value, value Value) bool {
   foreach v in values {
      if v == value {
        return true
      }
   }

  return false
}
```

This algorithm works good. But are there any better and more efficient ways to find the numbers without using any third party code?

Comment: One way is to create a hash-map of all the elements in all the lists and take an intersection of them. If you do not want to do that and can modify the ordering of the values in the lists, you can sort the lists and run an intersection on all the lists. The first method would run in linear time and the second would run in O(N * log N)

Comment: Use sorting and pointers to move through each list simultaneously. If you would be using hashmaps, you will have to manage frequency of numbers as well. For example, `36,41,41` could be a intersection of all 4 lists where `41` appears 2 times in each of them.

Comment: Yeah.. For big lists of numbers solution could be based on transform list (array, slice) to something like set (in go `map[int]struct{}`). Possible cheat is use sorted slices, where is easy to crete an intersection.

Comment: Count occurrences of every number. In the final step select those for which the number of occurrences is equal to the number of collections. If duplicates are allowed some extra attention will be needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algorithm model for Intersection of several sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264544/algorithm-model-for-intersection-of-several-sets)

Comment: Also, you don't have to use *third-party* software: sets are implemented with hashing in many languages.  For instance, this would be a one-liner in Python, with (Counter) or without (set) duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help. This is in js code.

```
const x = [[8,36,23,51,41], [2,19,23,36,41], [7,36,23,41,2], [41,2,47,36,51]];

findDuplicates = (arr) => {
    let ans = [];
    if(arr.length === 0) return ans;
    ans = arr[0];
    for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ans = arr[i].filter((a) => ans.includes(a));
    }
    return ans;
};

console.log(findDuplicates(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to do this in linear time. I would iterate through one of the lists and check each number for presence in the others. The other lists would need to be hashsets for `O(1)` lookups.

Something like this:

```py
numbers = [
  [8, 36, 23, 51, 41],
  [2, 19, 23, 36, 41],
  [7, 36, 23, 41, 7],
  [41, 2, 47, 36, 51]
]

lookup = [set(l) for l in numbers[1:]]
result = [x for x in numbers[0] if all(x in l for l in lookup)]

print(result)  # prints [36, 41]
```

or as @AndrewScott suggested just intersect the sets

```
lookup = [set(l) for l in numbers]
result = set.intersection(*lookup)
```